# Construction of a linear function $\wedge^k V \longrightarrow \wedge^k W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V,W \in K-Vect$, $f:V \longrightarrow W$ linear.
I need to construct a linear function $\wedge^kf:\wedge^k V\longrightarrow \wedge ^k W$ using the universal property.
For $V$, I got $f':V^k \longrightarrow W$ $K-linear$ and alternant so there is a unique $\overline{f}:\wedge^kV \longrightarrow W$ linear such that $f'=\overline{f}\wedge$, where $\wedge:V^k \longrightarrow \wedge ^k V$ is an alternant function.
The same for $W$.
Can't seem to join these properties and get the result, any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would $f':V^k\to W$ be alternant or even well defined? The mapping
$$f'':V^k\to W^k\to \wedge^k W$$ on the other hand...

Comment: I think i got the idea, thanks!

Comment: Do consider typing the details as an answer!! You would get more feedback, upvotes et cetera :-)